# Merge type of variable with token

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, typeof

I want to have a macro, which can merge the type of a variable with another token to create a new token. A random example:

```
int var;
int make_token(var);
```

This would become:

```
int var;
int var_int;
```

I've tried to define the macro like so:

```
#define make_token(x) x ## _ ## typeof(x)
```

But the whole thing gets expanded to:

```
int var;
int var_typeof(var)
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to pass the type of the variable in the parameters of the macro?

Comment: I don't think so.  The preprocessor has almost no knowledge of the language itself.

Comment: I believe you can do it with a double macro. `#define type_macro(x) typeof(x)`    `#define make_token(x) x ## _ ## type_macro(x)`. Try it, but don't take my word for it that it works.

Comment: I find the term 'token' confusing, and would prefer 'identifier'.

Comment: @SergeyL. Already tried that, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `typeof` is determined in a later phase of compilation, way after preprocessing, this is impossible.

Also `typeof` does not expand to a type identifier; it does not work at the textual/code level, but at the semantic level instead.  It's a keyword the compiler interprets and uses to determine the type for its internal data structures.

Only thing you can do is to add the type to the macro:

```
#define TYPED_VARIABLE(type, identifier) type identifier ## _ ## type
```

However, as a wise man recently said: "Using Hungarian notation is brainless and is a huge error, so don't do it!"  I fully agree.

Comment: +1 for the correct idea. The vocabulary that you are using is disturbing, though. The preprocessor is by definition (and in reality for most compilers) just a phase during compilation and not running "before compilation".

Comment: So does 'compile-time' include preprocessing?  I don't think so: With compile-time we're referring to mainly the semantic analysis & processing.  [Also the preprocessor is a separate program that is called by the compiler.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

Comment: I would upvote this if you could please add that "but using Hungarian notation is brainless and is a huge error, so don't do it".

Comment: @meaning-matters, the c standard distinguishes different "translation phases", section 5.1.1.2, preprocessing are phases 1 to 6. Modern compilers do these phases all in one go, such that they are able to track macro replacement back to the source, so all of this is "compile-time". If you mean a phase of semantic interpretation then say so, it is phase 7 in the C standard.

Comment: @JensGustedt I corrected to bring it in line with what you say, and with my second statement.  Thanks!

Comment: @H2CO3 There you go sir :-)  Please upvote now.  I've always hated Hungarian style anyways.

Comment: @H2CO3 Had a look at you profile and it's funny you're Hungarian.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a macro for each type you want to define.